# Cals table styling

Tags: html, css, formatting, css-tables

I have the below HTML table (cals table), here I need some CSS which shows the output as in the screenshot (the borders part).

```
<div class="para">To the Commissioner for Labour</div>
<table class="frame-all" colsep="1" rowsep="1" align="left" cols="4">
    <colgroup>
        <col class="colname-c1 colwidth-25.00%"></col>
        <col class="colname-c2 colwidth-25.00%"></col>
        <col class="colname-c3 colwidth-25.00%"></col>
        <col class="colname-c4 colwidth-25.00%"></col>
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" align="">
                I declare that the information given in this form is, to the 
                best of my knowledge, true and accurate.Signature: ___________
                (for and on behalf of the employer)Name (in block letters): ____
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="para">Position:</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="para">□ Sole proprietor</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="para">□ Partner</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="para"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="para"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="para">□ Manager</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="para">□ Officer</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="para"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="">Date: __________________________</td>
            <td>
                <div class="para"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="para">__________________________________</div>
                <div class="para">Chop of Company <span class="font-style-bolditalic">(Note 1)</span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="para align-center"><span class="font-style-bold">Part I</span></div>
<div class="para"> <span class="font-style-italic">A. Particulars of the employee</span>

</div>
<table class="frame-all" colsep="1" rowsep="1" align="left" cols="4">
    <colgroup>
        <col class="colname-c1 colwidth-25.00%"></col>
        <col class="colname-c2 colwidth-25.00%"></col>
        <col class="colname-c3 colwidth-25.00%"></col>
        <col class="colname-c4 colwidth-25.00%"></col>
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" align="">Name of employee (Surname first)</td>
            <td>
                <div class="para">Identity Card/Passport No.</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="para">Telephone No.</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="para">Fax No.</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="">Address</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="para">Date of birth</div>
                <div class="para">_____/_____/____</div>
                <div class="para">Day/Month/Year</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="para">Sex</div>
                <div class="para">□ Male&nbsp;&nbsp;□ Female</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="para">Occupation</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="para">An apprentice</div>
                <div class="para">□ Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;□ No</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

the expected and current outputs are as below

Current:
[image: Current]

Expected:
[image: Expected]

Thanks

Comment: Can you share what you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display borders around the table:

```
table {
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

To prevent borders around the cells (td):

```
table td {
    border: none;
}
```

To align the text to the left and to add some spacing:

```
table td {
    padding: 3px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

You can style the second table based on the example I have provided for the first.

Example: **http://jsfiddle.net/KTZL6/1**

This, however, is very basic css. You're probably best off working through a tutorial like http://www.cssbasics.com/introduction-to-css/ to get a grasp of it.

Comment: Hi @mritz here if you see for the first case(1 and 3 pics), there is only external border, that s what i want to achieve. Thanks for responding

Comment: Thanks @mritz_p, here came the real problem, when i add the second table here, it is showing both with only borders, where as i want one with brders and the other with no borders, sorry, i've updated your fiddle.

Comment: In this case you need to assign `id`s to target the specific tables. See http://jsfiddle.net/KTZL6/4/
This is CSS 101, so maybe you want to check out a tutorial after all...?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand right you only want remove borders.

```
<table class="frame-all" colsep="1" rowsep="1" align="left" cols="4" border="0">
```

You can use border="0", No need and external css file

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_border-style&preval=none for other border properties

Comment: Hi @user2688655:  here if you see for the first case(1 and 3 pics), there is only external border, that s what i want to achieve. Thanks for responding